# Ajax call in Grails

Tags: ajax, grails

I am new to Grails and facing the following problem. I have a popup which displays a form. I want to make an Ajax call to save( def save) the form details and stay in the same popup. But the Grails controller always renders the save.gsp. I believed that the Ajax call would prevent the rendering of the page but it is still happening. I have also tried using formRemote tag. The save.gsp is still getting rendered. I want to view the contents of save.gsp within the popup in updateMe placeholder. Instead the entire page is getting rendered. What is the best solution for this?

my code if given below:(its really raw n messy so pardon me!)

**configuration.gsp**

```
<g:formRemote name="myForm" on404="alert('not found!')" update="updateMe"
              url="[controller: 'configure', action:'save']">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Company Name</label>

        <g:textField name="CompanyName" class="form-control" value="${basicInstance?.CompanyName}" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Database</label>

        <g:textField name="DB" class="form-control" value="${basicInstance?.DB}" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username to Data base</label>

        <g:textField name="DBUserName" class="form-control" value="${basicInstance?.DBUserName}" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password to Data base</label>
        <g:textField name="DBPassword" class="form-control" value="${basicInstance?.DBPassword}" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>URL to Data base</label>

        <g:textField name="URL" class="form-control" value="${basicInstance?.URL}" />
    </div>

    <g:link>
        <div class="buttons">
            <span class="button"  ><g:submitButton name="save" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT"  /></span>
        </div>
    </g:link>

    <div id="updateMe"></div>
</g:formRemote>
```

**configureController**

```
package mdm

import groovy.sql.Sql

class ConfigureController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST"]

    def configuration={
        def basicInstance = new BasicDBInfo()

        basicInstance.properties=params

        return [basicInstance: basicInstance]
    }

    def save={

        def basicInstance = new BasicDBInfo(params)

        if (basicInstance.save(flush: true)) {

            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'BasicDBInfo.label', default: 'BasicDBInfo'), basicInstance.id])}"

            render(view: "save")
        }
        else {
            flash.message = "${message( args: [message(code: 'administrator.label', default: 'soemthing is wrong'), basicInstance.id])}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/vahidhedayati/modaldynamix and give this a try https://github.com/vahidhedayati/testmodaldynamix - It does what you are attempting to do - If you want it to keep the modalbox open then use the iframe method... there are a few variations and you may find the right one for you. from that I guess you could figure out where yours is going wrong

Comment: I think if you follow the plugin, you maybe able to just use it and save yourself the hassle. Maybe given plugin is not be the place to understand what is calling what :). An easier example is wschat plugin, install it set default auth type to admin in the Config.groovy and then goto the cog and choose book room. This calls a few functions that does near enough what u want. The source is in here: here https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/tree/master/grails-app/views/admin/ then _admin _inviteContainer _master book and so on.. u will need bootstrap.js

Comment: Hey thank you for the help! I figured out the solution. e.preventDefault was missing :)